# Ask author of duplicate question if question should be deleted

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

When a question has been closed as a duplicate, can we alert the author and ask 'Is this really what you're asking for?'

Then, if the author clicks Yes, auto delete the duplicate post?

Comment: The first part of your original question is already in place, if you have 3,000 reputation: [Cast close and reopen votes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). I removed that. Please see if I correctly summarized your feature request?

Comment: @Arjan As far as I know, closed questions with no upvotes are deleted periodically. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Shadow, at least *downvoted* unanswered questions [are gone after a month](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), or after a year with a zero score. Not sure if something specific applies to closed questions. (If you think that my edit was wrong, then please say so. I didn't grasp that from your comment?)

Comment: @Arjan thanks, I'm now following that post. I'm not the OP sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*-1* Automatic deletion is seldom a good idea. Also, duplicates are often differently stated, sometimes with a complete different wording then the original question. This opens up the possibility to find the answer to the same question on different ways and prevents that a duplicate gets asked over and over again, just because the wording is different.

Answer (score 6):

No we can't. Most of the dups come from people who have very little rep and should not have a veto on the curation of the site.