# Reputation shown in graph, and mortarboard awarded, for CW posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, community-wiki, daily-reputation-limit

I don't care, but just in case it's somehow important:

I was just awarded mortarboard, and it seems reputation from CW posts was erroneously taken into account. This reputation also shows in [my reputation graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rz4h.png).

(One upvote was cast on the CW question [in the short moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/86997/timeline) it took to ask a moderator to make it CW. The answer has always been CW. This may be related to a reputation recalc I triggered today, after deleting [an unrelated answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87174/ask-author-of-duplicate-question-if-question-should-be-deleted/87178#87178). My reputation report correctly shows 155 score for April 11th.)

Comment: The answer does not look like CW according to [revisions-list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/86998/revisions)

Comment: @YOU, yes, it *shows* different when making it CW *before* the first save. Changing it within the grace period actually does show it, and so does changing it afterwards. That's a bit odd indeed. (In all, there's 145 too much reputation, which is the total of both question and answer, minus 5 for the very first upvote on the question.)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Bug: my reputation history shows points for cw answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83388/bug-my-reputation-history-shows-points-for-cw-answers), though that does not mention mortarboard.

Comment: Aww, you got the Mortarboard? I was always looking up to you for getting as far as you have without hitting the cap. It was one of my early goals to see if I could hit 10k without ever hitting the cap, but [that plan got blown out of the water](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51585/what-is-the-largest-uncapped-reputation-gain-in-so-history). Well, at least in reality, you still haven't hit the cap. ♪

Comment: Maybe one day I will understand why hitting the cap is bad, or less fun, @Grace... ;-)

Comment: And, @Grace, [it happened to me before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79890/mortarboard-awarded-for-deleted-posts). I just didn't know I should feel sad about it! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an error occurring when a recalc was performed on a user.  A tweak to fix old unassociated posts was not correctly ignoring community wiki cases elsewhere.  This has been fixed and is rolling across the network at the time of this answer.

We'll recalc 500 users an hour in the background until this is complete everywhere (about 2 hours from now).  As an example: @Arjan [your rep was fixed by this process already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph).

Comment: Okidoki. I still have the mortarboard, if that is important.

Comment: @Arjan - Badges will be fixed in a deployment tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I thought this was a different issue, the same symptom is seen in the reputation tab:

[image]