# My SO reputation is inconsistent

Tags: support, reputation

Today at around 14:00 an answer from me was accepted and my reputation showed **745**.

4 hours later I checked again and my rep was back at **730**. I checked my reputation overview but there was nothing like -15 today.

It gets better, I added the values from my reputation overview and the result is 735 (+1 from the start would be a rep of **736**).

Could it be that an answer has been unaccepted and this is not reflected in the reputation overview? What is now correct?

Comment: Reputation is a wave on the river Stax, you never know when it dries or when it overflows. Just pay the ferryman a dime and enjoy the ride, you be surprised where it takes you.

Comment: What does http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation say?

Comment: @Bobby stackoverflow.com/reputation says 736. I triggered now a recalc there.

Comment: "The river Stax" Hahaha! ha! ha...

Comment: It probably is an unaccept, but note that a [global recalc is in progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87190/reputation-shown-in-graph-and-mortarboard-awarded-for-cw-posts/88040#88040), so people will be seeing rep changes from that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an "unaccept" of an answer will drop your current rep by -15 but will not show in your overview.  That is because there is nothing that happened today that subtracted -15 from your rep, instead something that added +15 to your rep disappeared.

The same effect could be seen with votes that are changed.

Comment: OK, I understand the system that +15 from another day disappeared, but it would be interesting to know which answer was unaccepted.

Comment: @stema - I _would_ be interesting, but unfortunately the powers that be have decided that it is not to be.

Comment: I saw a -15 in my reputation overview from an unaccepted formerly-accepted answer a few days ago.  I looked to see and it's the only thing it could have been.  The unaccept happened more than a day after the accept, which may have played into it.

Answer (score 5):

The first case means that an accepted answer was unaccepted.

If you want to see what your rep should be (minus stuff that was deleted) then
go to your [reputation summary](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).