# Reputation from bounties not counted on community wiki posts in most recent rep recalc

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, community-wiki

According to [Sam Saffron (aka waffles ♦)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles), [a recent fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87190/reputation-shown-in-graph-and-mortarboard-awarded-for-cw-posts/88040#88040) by [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) to how votes are counted on Community Wiki posts was deployed, and many users had their reputation automatically recalculated to account for these changes. This recalc resulted in a massive loss of rep for a few users, but not for most. From my research, it appears that bounties on CW posts are not being counted:

- My reputation went down by 497 points
- I have received a single +500 point bounty on [one CW post](https://superuser.com/questions/230139/where-should-i-find-drivers-for-my-laptop-if-it-didnt-come-with-a-driver-disk/230150#230150), and several bounties [on others](https://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu/242153#242153)
- The bounty for the CW post did not appear in my reputation audit
- The other bounties did appear in my reputation audit
- I was missing only 3 points fewer than the value of the bounty, which matches up almost perfectly, accounting for a few points due to deleted posts or other small changes
- As an additional check, I looked at the recalc results for a user well known for going after bounties. His reputation had also gone down by a significant amount - about 350 points. This is another indication that the bug is likely tied to bounties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for identifying this!  It was indeed a bug with fixing votes on old posts (cleaning up historical vote values that were incorrect, which shown as bad de-normalized data, e.g. the rep graph/report).

This will be fixed in the next build on the code side, once that's deployed we'll need to recalc the affected users (about 1100 on Stack Overflow for reference).

The build will go out tonight, then we'll push a recalc job after that, so by this weekend everyone affected should get their CW bounties returned (and suggested edit approvals as well!).

---

*Update:* The recalc for affected users is rolling across the network now, all should be well in a few hours.  @nhinkle - I recalced your rep manually as a test case, your CW bounties [are now restored](https://superuser.com/users/20088/nhinkle?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph).

Comment: This affects all sites or just Stack Overflow, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Grace - All sites, only for users who have had a recalc (most self-triggered) in the past 3 days...the fix will be applied everywhere of course.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Glad this is fixed now.