# Mortarboard badges being awarded as a result of bounties after recalc

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

(Preface: I'm not on a badge witch hunt or anything, just saw something peculiar and potentially buggy)

[This user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1786/john-sheehan) recently got `Mortarboard` but [the only day he's gone over the rep cap is because of a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1786/john-sheehan?tab=reputation), and that was 3 months ago.  [The `Mortarboard` FAQ description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) states that Mortarboard is earned by

> - Exceed the rep cap
>
>   - Exceeding the cap is defined as earning ≥200 reputation in one day from a combination of upvotes and accepts, but not bounties

But there's been no days like that as far as I can tell.  Is this a bug?

**edit**: and also the answer that got upvotes on the day of that bounty was to a CW question that's always been CW (plus, he would have gotten 250 + the upvote rep since the bounty is immune to the rep cap)

Comment: I also [got it recently](http://stackoverflow.com/users/143295/renesis?tab=reputation) from a bounty.  I had no upvotes that day, only the bounty and an accept (315 total). Unrelated to CW at all, and also got it immediately, not after a recalc.

Comment: Seeing as Nick Craver has updated the post to say that bounties are in fact included, I'm thinking this is by design. The delay of it for 3 months, then, is explained by YOU's answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've updated the FAQ, since it doesn't actually describe what the badge does.  The badge awards for the sum of votes for that day, meaning bounties are included (they're a vote on the back-end).  The mortarboard badge is given for *any* day in which your net rep was >= 200.

I updated the FAQ to reflect badge description changes coming out in tonight's build:

- **Mortarboard**: Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day
- **Epic**: Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days
- **Legendary**: Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days

To be clear *the badges have not changed*, the descriptions were always inaccurate since it's a net 200 total that's checked...we're simply clarifying this.  At the same time, we're taking the chance to remove the mention of the reputation cap...since it's not really related to the badge.

Comment: Is it strictly greater than 200? ie. > 200 or >= 200?

Comment: @ChrisF - errrr, "at least" it what it *will* say....

Comment: So days where you hit the cap *just from votes* don't count any more? You have to have an acceptance or bounty award too?

Comment: @ChrisF - no, they count, *anything* (besides association) totaling 200 counts, the SQL for the badge isn't changing at all, only the descriptions.

Comment: Ah - hopefully this should remove the confusion over when the Epic and Legendary badges get awarded. Will the numbers at the bottom of the `\reputation` report match the SQL? (Sorry - I missed your edit when posting that previous comment).

Comment: @ChrisF - Yep! I just left an answer on that here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/how-is-it-possible-to-reach-the-rep-cap-without-exceeding-it/88530#88530 If they *don't* match for any reason, it's a bug, let us know :)

Comment: @Nick: There's still unspecified behavior in the FAQ wording. Is that the net gain or the positive gain, i.e. what about downvotes cast and received, bounties given, deletions, rescinded upvotes, …?

Comment: @Gilles - it's net gain for the day, deleted (rescinded) votes and deleted questions don't count, downvotes and such (again if they aren't deleted) do.  The same components that would make up or be excluded from your overall rep....the same rules apply here.

Comment: @NickCraver, I hope you can look at this question, it doesn't seem like Epic works the same anymore, since I got it but the rep page is now showing me as having 50 days.  I'm not sure if the badge works differently, or there is just a problem with the rep page.  It may be the bug you refer to in your comment above to ChrisF.

Comment: Does the +2 you get from accepting an answer count?  That's kind of a vote (the flip side of a vote, anyway), *but* it's one you control so it might be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Could be because of this recalc?

[Reputation from bounties not counted on community wiki posts in most recent rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88280/reputation-from-bounties-not-counted-on-community-wiki-posts-in-most-recent-rep-r/88334#88334)

> The build will go out **tonight**, then we'll push a recalc job after that, so by this weekend everyone affected should get their CW bounties returned (and suggested edit approvals as well!).

Comment: Possibly for this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/31918/revisions  but according to the timeline those votes were spread out a lot and he never had a ton on a single day even prior to that answer becoming CW.  His other answers all appear to have started as CW

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo, According to my understanding, bounties are also count towards badges, but no idea when I see the post you linked/quoted. Could be my wrong memory or today fix effected that.