# Upvote-only-reached rep cap badge request

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request, daily-reputation-badges

Upon [checking your reputation](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation), the summary report (at the bottom) includes:

```
days represented ??
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on ?? days
earned at least 200 reputation on ?? days
earned ?? reputation from suggested edits
```

How about a badge (collection, bronze/silver/gold) for upvote-only-reached rep cap?

I would think that this achievement is more difficult to reach than [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic) & [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary), but would be fairly "useless" in terms of [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Those badges were already set up that way previously. They were changed *away* from that. It doesn't make much sense to now go back and make it a requirement on badges again.</s>

The above is actually inaccurate. I've since found [Nick Craver's response about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526) which indicates that the badges *never* followed the reputation cap but have always just looked for a total of 200 rep earned on the day. The change in badge description was only to clarify what the badge *actually did*, and not how it functions.

Previously, [they were listed as follows](http://web.archive.org/web/20100102050832/https://stackoverflow.com/badges):

> - **Mortarboard** - Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time
> - **Epic** - Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days
> - **Legendary** - Hit the daily reputation cap on 150 days

---

That being said now, there really isn't any need for actual reputation cap badges. Perhaps there could be a single bronze badge for hitting the *actual* reputation cap for the first time, but the existing daily-reputation badges already cover this for the most part.

Badges are meant to encourage positive behavior, and whether or not you hit the reputation cap doesn't really matter when encouraging a user to continue asking and answering in a single day. The outcome for both would be the same, and I imagine the pattern for awarding both badges would be about the same too. You'd essentially be getting two badges for the same work you've been completing.

Comment: Do you know *why* they were changed away to the current definition?

Comment: @Werner: I've updated this with more accurate information from Nick.