# Bounties and Epic/legendary progress

Tags: support, bounties, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

The Epic badge says:

> Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times

If I offer a -100 bounty and get 230 for 20 upvotes and 2 accepts, does it count as "earned 200 daily reputation"?

I obviously can hardly earn 200 rep with -100 from a bounty (well, I can if 7 my answers get accepted, but that's unlikely).

Comment: You can do it. Look at a [standard user daily reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation).

Comment: @dystroy yeah, but on TeX.SX my chances are low.

Comment: Hum... yes... it's done by the top users but obviously it's much harder...

Comment: how often do you offer a +100 bounty? a few more days of getting 200 rep isn't a big deal if you already did it 50 times.

Comment: @Ryathal It's as well a matter of concept: you never want to know how things work?

Comment: when it comes to badges I don't really care, especially those based on a lot of repetitive actions as they are really just marking length of time spent participating, voting 200 or 215 times or hitting the rep cap 50 or 55 times or editing 100 or 110 posts isn't a big deal.

Comment: "I can if 7 my answers get accepted" You could also earn bounty from someone else, although you would need to time it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your total at the end of the day counts; if you set a bounty on a question that puts your total for the day below 200, that day does *not* count.

To quote [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#comment219240_88526):

> *anything* (besides association) totaling 200 counts.