# Are accepts considered for the epic badge

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Are accepts considered towards the 200 daily reputation that a user should get in a day that counts for the Epic or Legendary badge? That is if I have a day where I have 205 reputation but 30 of them are from accepted answers, will this day still be counted towards the 50 needed for the Epic badge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to earn 200 points in a UTC day; accepts, suggested edits, upvotes, accepting answers on your own questions, bounties, everything but the association bonus counts.

From the [Badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on the Epic badge:

> - silver; awarded once; same family as Mortarboard (bronze), Legendary (gold)
> - Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days
>
>   - All reputation activities, including up and down votes, accepted answers, bounties, and suggested edits count towards this badge **except**
>       for association bonuses, which do not count.
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time
> - Sources: [An answer and comments from Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526)

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer!

Comment: @izomorphius at the bottom of [stackoverflow.com/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) it will tell exactly *earned at least 200 reputation on [x] days*

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter really helpful link. Thank you

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Actually, previous bug reports have shown that value to be inaccurate. It's only an approximation.

Comment: @animuson [oh I see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161428/148672) well that's a bummer.