# Mortarboard badge not awarded

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bounties, association

This is my total reputation for today:

[image]

I just started my carreer as an active member on the StackExchance sites, so I don't have the `Mortarboard` badge yet:

[image]

I am assuming either the 100 rep bounty or the 100 rep association bonus did not count towards the daily reputation badge. Is this intended? If so, I think the user should get some information about this - for example in the notification he gets.

I found something that actually makes me think this is a bug. When hovering over my account name I get this:

[image]

The reputation is displayed there but the sum isn't right in the column `today`.

Comment: BTW, reputation changes are public info, so you need not blur them out.

Comment: I know, I was doing it to keep it simple to look at.

Comment: Now you're at +205 so you should get the badge within few hours.

Comment: Congrats, you got it! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hehe. thanks, and at the same time the question got cleared up!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [the Badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/187824) for Mortarboard:

> - **Reputation points earned for associating accounts** or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do **not** count for the badge.

So you did not earn badge because you actually earned [165 (265-100) reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040925/typ1232?tab=reputation).

you have a chance to earn that badge, just 35 more reputation required to earn that badge

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with a good source. Maybe this sould be made clearer with a "This does not count towards daily reputation badges" in the notification "You've earned a bonus for your associated accounts: +100 reputation"

Answer (score 7):

The badge is not awarded instantly. A script runs occasionally to award it. Give it some time and it should show up.

Additionally, [bounties count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526/167443), but it looks like the association bonus probably doesn't.

Comment: I noticed this with other badges, but as you see in the image I reached 200 reputation about 7 hours ago. I usually takes up to 5 minutes. edit: actually it was 25 minutes ago, sorry

Comment: Could be a couple of days.

Comment: @typ1232 It looks like the association bonus might not count. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: I just added another picture

Comment: The association bonus does not count from my experience. I had something similar happen where I had over 200 rep in a day with the association bonus and never received Mortarboard, and I didn't have a bounty awarded, so my guess is that association bonus doesn't count.