# Progress Bar for Epic Badge

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, daily-reputation-badges

The epic badge requires you to get 200 daily reputation 50 times. Reputation points for accepted answers count towards the 200 points.

However, the progress bar does not include reputation points from accepted answers.

For example, at the time of writing, my reputation today is +220:

```
10 * 13 upvotes + 6 * 15 accepted answers = 220
```

The days earned bar has already increased from 15 to 16 today.

However, the today's rep bar shows 130/200.

[image: Epic badge progress]

Comment: @DavidPostill Accepted answers **do** count towards the badge, so I think they should be included in the progress bar as well. Personally, I can see that I am progressing towards the epic badge, even though I only hit 200 points including accepted answers. See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#88526).

Comment: @DavidPostill All positive reputation changes for the day count towards the badge, except the association bonus. The progress bar is incorrect.