# WAAAAAH my rep has been reduced

Tags: feature-request

I know SO recalculates rep from time to time. Would it be possible to show where and on what questions/answers it happens?

Just a thought

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no biggie, but you misspelled "Eeeeek."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation recalculation started just a few hours ago, according to this

[Reputation from bounties not counted on community wiki posts in most recent rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88280/reputation-from-bounties-not-counted-on-community-wiki-posts-in-most-recent-rep-r/88334#88334)

After any rep recalc, your reputations on deleted posts will not be counted.

Comment: It's important to note this is not a global recalc, only the affected users were issued a recalc, about 1100 in all on Stack Overflow.

Comment: AFAIK, rep on deleted posts has **never** counted...  [Not since '09, anyway.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep)

Comment: @John, but rep on deleted posts stay until it gets recalc.

Comment: True.  The way you phrased your last sentence lead me to believe you meant something else.

Comment: @John, that is probably because of my bad english, how about that now?

Comment: It still seems to me like your saying that this recalc is different from past ones.  Probably not a big deal, but I suggested an edit for you anyway.